# Total probability problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I currently have log files all off different sizes, and I am trying to calculate the total probability of an event that occurs being an error.

For example:

> Log file #1: Has a total of 1000 entries and 20 of them entries are errors so the conditional probability for that file would be 20/1000 = 0.02
>
> Log File #2: Has a total of 2500 entries and 35 of them entries are errors so the conditional probability for that file would be 35/2500 = 0.014
>
> Log File #3: Has a total of 5000 entries and 60 of them entries are errors so the conditional probability for that file would be 60/5000 = 0.012

I was wondering how I would get the total probability of an event that occurs being an error for all the log files combined?

Any help would be much appreciated, and if you could use the example I gave to explain to me it would be great.  The events in the log file are completely different, the log files are for completely different systems.

Would it be `(amount of errors/total number of events) = 115/8500 = 0.0135`?

Comment: If the files are for "completely different systems," then what exactly does it mean to talk about the "probability of ... an error"?

Comment: @whuber i want to calculate total probability of an event being an error for all these systems combined. 
like my end goal is to get a general probability of an error occurring in any of these systems even though there not related. Sorry if that doesn't make sense

Comment: You need to make assumptions about how the systems are related. Can you assume that all systems have the same probability of error?

Comment: @jarad Thank for your reply,No that my main problem i cant assume that any of the system have the same error probability because there not related and each one will more than likely have a different error probability.

Answer (score 1):

From an IT point of view, it doesn't matter that the log files are coming from disparate systems. All of the log events originating from systems under hacker9116's purview constitute a single log stream of events consisting of (State, System) pairs and as a result, the probability of an error can be approximated from the log stream by the law of total probability.

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable taking on Error and Non-error representing the state of the log event. Let $S$ be a discrete random variable taking on non-negative integer values represent the system generating the log event.

Based on the information provided by hacker9116.

$\mathbb{P}(X = \text{Error} | S = s) \approx \begin{cases} \frac{20}{1000} & s = 0 \\ \frac{35}{2500} & s = 1 \\ \frac{60}{5000} & s = 2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ , $\mathbb{P}(S = s) \approx \begin{cases} \frac{1000}{8500} & s = 0 \\ \frac{2500}{8500} & s = 1 \\ \frac{5000}{8500} & s = 2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Given the law of total probability: $\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(X = \text{Error}) = \sum_{s = 0}^{2} \mathbb{P}(X = \text{Error} | S = s) \mathbb{P}(S = s)$,

$\implies \mathbb{P}(X = \text{Error}) = \frac{20}{1000} \frac{1000}{8500} + \frac{35}{2500} \frac{2500}{8500} + \frac{60}{5000}\frac{5000}{8500} = \frac{115}{8500}$.

So I would argue that your approach is correct hacker9116.

Comment: This answer assumes the log files represent a common period of time, or at least equal time periods.

Comment: @whuber I am sorry, I am not exactly good a maths, but what do you mean " the log files represent a common period of time, or at least equal time periods." and how does that change the equation again sorry for questions.